How to hide decompilation items in Solution Explorer file filter
It's hard for me to phrase this question, but the image tells the story.

When I use Solution Explorer file filter, then so-called 'External resources' are displayed along with the regular source code files. These are probably from automatically de-compiled DLL files. Since those DLLs are made from the source code, these are inevitably the same source files. Hence the duplication and it's annoying. Especially when multiple finds exist.
Is there a way to disable such finds?
